# alter table to create columns for other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

can anyone help me with creating column for table A that are from table B ?

let's say i have table B:

```
column name:WORDS
      row 1:ONE
      row 2:TWO
      row 3:THREE
```

and want to have table A:

```
column name: ONE | TWO | THREE
```

I need this to be created and not some VIEW

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with this exactly? My first instinct tells me you didn't hit any ACID before designing your database.

Comment: i need to periodicaly create table B, but i need a source for column names.. can do it in php, but is there any way of doing it in sql only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like...

```
create function create_my_table () as 
$$
declare
v_t text[];
begin
select array_agg(distinct quote_ident(words) ||' text' ) into v_t from table_B;
EXECUTE  'CREATE TABLE tableA (' || array_to_string(v_t,',') ||' );';
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

select create_my_table;
```

Comment: thanks.. seems to do the job, but i'll stick to create tables with php if it has to look like that.

Comment: In Postgresql 9.0 (due out in less than a month)....this would be reduced to (not much better, but some)...

DO
$$
EXECUTE  'CREATE TABLE tableA (' || (SELECT string_agg(distinct quote_ident(words) || ' text',',') from table_B) ||' )';
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostgreSQL's INHERITS syntax:

-- create tableB as a template

```
create table tableB(one varchar,two varchar,three varchar);
```

-- create tableA

```
create table tableA() INHERITS(tableB);
```